# NetBeans ubuntu monospaced plane 15 for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I use NetBeans IDE for Java web development, and I really enjoy NetBeans Monospaced font for Ubuntu. But now I started using Eclipse for Android projects and I would like to know if there's anyway of setting that font for Eclipse. At the Eclipse "fonts and colors" settings for java there is only one `Monospace` available, and not the Monospaced plane which is available for NetBeans 7.1.

This is the NetBeans awesome font I would like to set for Eclipse as well
[image]

This is the current Eclipse font
[image]

Comment: I think that this would be considered a general computer use question, not a programming question, since you're not asking a question about coding.

Comment: I would advise asking it on superuser.com (Like stackoverflow, but for general computer use, as opposed to computer programming)